# Does the sum of three vectors originating from the centroid of a triangle and pointing to the angles always sum to zero?

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

Consider an equilateral triangle as the one given in the figure below:

[image]

Assume $$\vec{E_1},\vec{E_2},\vec{E_3}$$ are vectors (for instance complex numbers in the complex plane) originating from the centroid (N) and pointing each one to their respective angle (each vector is parallel to a median).

For an equilateral triangle, the property (property 1):

$$\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2}+\vec{E_3}=0 $$ holds true.

Now consider a generic triangle where the three vectors still originate at the centroid (N). My question is: is the above property (property 1) still true for a generic triangle?

Additional information: this question is related to an electrotechnical problem and to a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303233/what-hypothesis-are-needed-to-support-the-following-argument-on-a-three-phase-sy) I originally asked on Electronics SE. As far as my understanding goes, this geometrical property is the key to answering the [electrotechnical question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303233/what-hypothesis-are-needed-to-support-the-following-argument-on-a-three-phase-sy), therefore I thought it could be appropriate to ask it here. If you wish to know more about the original question please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: If a triangle has vertices $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, and $(x_3,y_3)$, then the coordinates of the centroid are $$(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},\frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3})$$

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer Why don't you flesh that out into an answer?

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer I'm sorry I don't get it, I know that the sum of the medians (considered as vectors) should be zero, but I still can't solve the question above. If you know how to answer my question could you please do it? I'll happily accept the answer !

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer ok, thanks anyway! Yeah, I looked for properties of triangles and I found that the sum of medians (considered as vectors) is always zero but nothing more. I and my friends were a bit puzzled by the original electrotechnical question which was on our test... however the book doesn't explain the proof.

Comment: This is almost trivial if you use [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system).

Comment: @mickkk The vectors end at the corresponding vertex, I presume? Then note that the vectors can be written as $(A - N), (B-N)$, and $(C -N)$. Now use Franklin's observation.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes they end at the corresponding vertex. Now I see, I think our mistake was to focus too much on the technical side and lose track of the basics. Thank you everyone for helping out!

Comment: The centroid of a triangle can be defined as the point $N$ such that $\overrightarrow{PN} = \cfrac{1}{3}\left(\overrightarrow{PA}+\overrightarrow{PB}+\overrightarrow{PC}\right)$ for an arbitrary point $P\,$. Now take $P \equiv N\,$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof:
By a preexisting formula, if the coordinates of the vertices of a triangle are $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$, then the centroid is the point
$$(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3})$$
If this is so, then the horizontal parts of each of the vectors are $\frac{-2x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$, $\frac{x_1-2x_2+x_3}{3}$, and $\frac{x_1+x_2-2x_3}{3}$, and the vertical parts are $\frac{-2y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}$, $\frac{y_1-2y_2+y_3}{3}$, and $\frac{y_1+y_2-2y_3}{3}$. To sum the vectors, sum the horizontal and vertical parts. The horizontal part will be
$$\frac{-2x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}+\frac{x_1-2x_2+x_3}{3}+\frac{x_1+x_2-2x_3}{3} = 0$$
Which is $0$, and the vertical part will be
$$\frac{-2y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}+\frac{y_1-2y_2+y_3}{3}+\frac{y_1+y_2-2y_3}{3} = 0$$
Which is also $0$. All $3$ vectors cancel out. QED.

Comment: i.e.: centroid of a triangle = center of mass of three equal point-masses at the vertices=(by definition) point from which the sum of  vector distances from the masses is null.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the property you wish to prove is an affine property. So, yes, if it holds for a single triangle it holds for all triangles.

In more detail, an affine transformation is determined by where any three noncollinear points get mapped to, and since the vertices of a triangle are such, then any two triangles are affine equivalent.

The centroid (or barycenter) of any finite set of points is a particular weighted sum of the points with all weights equal, and the sum of vectors from the centroid to the points is zero while weighted sums are an affine property.

Some good information is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation.

Comment: It's a good observation but probably inaccessible on its merits to the OP posting above.  Perhaps you could "decorate" your brief response with some embedded links to explain the concept *affine property*, etc. for Readers disposed to pursue it further.